# how to compute the proportion of words by day in quanteda?

Tags: r, quanteda

Consider this simple example

```
tibble(text = c('a grande latte with soy milk',
                'black coffee no room',
                'latte is a latte',
                'coke, diet coke'),
       myday = c(ymd('2018-01-01','2018-01-01','2018-01-03','2018-01-03'))) %>% 
  corpus() %>% 
  tokens() %>% 
  dfm()
Document-feature matrix of: 4 documents, 14 features (71.4% sparse).
4 x 14 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
       features
docs    a grande latte with soy milk black coffee no room is coke , diet
  text1 1      1     1    1   1    1     0      0  0    0  0    0 0    0
  text2 0      0     0    0   0    0     1      1  1    1  0    0 0    0
  text3 1      0     2    0   0    0     0      0  0    0  1    0 0    0
  text4 0      0     0    0   0    0     0      0  0    0  0    2 1    1
```

I am interested in getting the proportion of the word `coffee`, aggregated by day.

That is, for day `2018-01-01` we can see that there are 10 words (`a` `grande` `latte` `with` `soy` `milk` `black` `coffee` `no` `room`) and `coffee` is mentioned only once. So the proportion is 1/10. Same reasoning for the other days.

How can I do that in `quanteda`? Of course, the idea is to avoid materializing the sparse matrix into a dense matrix.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy and part of the core **quanteda** design decision to pass through your docvars from the corpus object to "downstream" objects such as a dfm.  You can solve this using `dfm_group()` by the `myday` docvar and then weighting.

First, to make your example fully reproducible, and to assign your dfm object a name:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.4.3
library("tibble")
library("lubridate")

dfmat <- tibble(
  text = c(
    "a grande latte with soy milk",
    "black coffee no room",
    "latte is a latte",
    "coke, diet coke"
  ),
  myday = c(ymd("2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-03"))
) %>%
  corpus() %>%
  tokens() %>%
  dfm()
```

Now it's just two operations to get your desired result.

```r
dfmat2 <- dfm_group(dfmat, groups = "myday") %>%
  dfm_weight(scheme = "prop")
dfmat2
## Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 14 features (42.9% sparse).
## 2 x 14 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
##             features
## docs             a grande latte with soy milk black coffee  no room    is
##   2018-01-01 0.100    0.1  0.10  0.1 0.1  0.1   0.1    0.1 0.1  0.1 0    
##   2018-01-03 0.125    0    0.25  0   0    0     0      0   0    0   0.125
##             features
## docs         coke     ,  diet
##   2018-01-01 0    0     0    
##   2018-01-03 0.25 0.125 0.125

dfmat2[, "coffee"]
## Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 1 feature (50.0% sparse).
## 2 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
##             features
## docs         coffee
##   2018-01-01    0.1
##   2018-01-03    0
```